# Prove that the dimension of the centralizer of a Jordan block is $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let the Jordan block of size $n$ and parameter $\lambda$ be $J_n(\lambda)$
$$J_n(\lambda) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 1&&&&  \\ 
 &  \lambda& 1 && \\ 
 &  &  \ddots & \ddots & \\ 
 &  &  &  \lambda&1 \\ 
 &  &  &  &\lambda 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Show that the dimension of the centralizer of $J_n(\lambda)$ is $n$.

Through working this out explicitly for small $n$, I've worked that the centralizer for $J_n(\lambda)$, $C$,  is of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & \ddots &m  & n\\ 
 &  a& b & \ddots & m\\ 
 &  &  \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\ 
 &  &  &  a&b \\ 
 &  &  &  &a 
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $C$ is upper triangular where the entries in each diagonal are equal to one another. However I'm unable to formulate a proof for this. I think splitting up $J_n(\lambda)$ to $\lambda I_n + N$ might be useful, since if C centralizes $N$, and it centralizes $I_n$, then consequently $J_n(\lambda)$ as well. But I'm stuck as to proving it

Comment: If you write $N$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}E_{i,i+1}$ and $A=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}E_{ij}$ then it's routine to show that $AN=NA$ implies $A$ has the form you describe.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I'm not quite clear what $E$ and $a_{ij}$ is in this context

Comment: The canonical basis of the matrix space: $E_{ij}$ has a $1$ in the $(i,j)$-place and $0$ elsewhere. They multiply as $E_{ij}E_{kl}=E_{il}$ if $j=k$, $=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I've written $N=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}E_{i,i+1}$ and $A=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}E_{ij}$ and have worked out that $AN= a_{11}E_{12}+a_{21}E_{22}+\cdots +a_{n1}E_{n2} +a_{12}E_{13}+a_{22}E_{23}+\cdots +a_{n2}E_{n3}+ a_{1,n-1}E_{1n}+a_{2,n-1}E_{2n}+\cdots+a_{n,n-1}E_{nn}$
and $NA=a_{21}E_{11}+a_{22}E_{12}+\cdots +a_{2n}E_{1n} +a_{31}E_{21}+a_{32}E_{22}+\cdots +a_{3n}E_{2n}+ a_{n1}E_{n-1,1}+a_{n2}E_{n-1,2}+\cdots+a_{n,n}E_{n-1,n}$, but how do I move on to showing the form of A. I see that equating the two implies some $a_{ij}=0$ but I'm struggling to generalise everything to show the form

Comment: I think it's clearer to write the thing in proper $\sum$ form. You can then see how the first column is zero apart from $a_{11}$ and that for $r\leqslant s$  we have that $a_{r,s}=a_{r+1,s+1}$.